# Azure Log Analytics Excluded Specific Containers

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I have a cluster and one of the namespaces generates a lot of useless logs and I dont want to funnel them to Azure Log Analytics due to cost. Is there any way to config ALA to not accept or record data from that namespace?

---

Answer below is correct. Here are some links to azure documentation aand a config map template to control container agent config

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-agent-config

https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-docker/blob/ci_feature_prod/Kubernetes/container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the settings as below to exclude specific namespaces

```
[log_collection_settings.stderr]          
   enabled = true          
   exclude_namespaces = ["kube-system", "dev-test"]
```