# Azure AKS + Azure Application Insights -> Exclude capture of pod output?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-aks, azure-monitor

Is there a way to exclude pod/console output from collection from Azure Monitor?

My apps are generating way too many logs, causing a massive bill... and the problem is that the team is not using it in any way...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Log Analytics Excluded Specific Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837926/azure-log-analytics-excluded-specific-containers)

Comment: Are these helpful? [Data collection settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-agent-config#data-collection-settings) , [Controlling ingestion to reduce cost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-cost#controlling-ingestion-to-reduce-cost) [Azure Monitor for Containers — Optimizing data collection settings for cost](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-monitor-for-containers-optimizing-data-collection-settings-for-cost-ce6f848aca32)